# Equal power series implications about the coefficients of the power series.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem:

Let $\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} b_n x^n$ both being a power series which have the same radius of convergence say r>0 and for all x in (-r,r) this equality is true. Show that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for all $ n>=0$

My attempt:

$\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{f_1^{n}(0) x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} a_n x^n=\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} b_n x^n=\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{f_2^{n}(0) x^n}{n!}$

Therefore $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ and therefore the coefficients of the power series of both are equal, the coefficients are defined by the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ hence the sequences must be equal.

A solution:

Consider $\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} (a_n-b_n) x^n $ since $\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} b_n x^n$  hence $f(x)=0$ with x in (-r,r)

This gives $a_n-b_n=\frac{f^{n}(0) x^n}{n!}=0$ for all n, therefore $a_n=b_n=0$ for all n.

My Questions:

Is my attempt correct?
If so what approach is better and hence which should I adopt for other similar questions I may encounter?

Comment: Your argument rests on the claim that the derivative of the sum of the series is the sum of the derivatives of the terms of the series. This is a true claim for a convergent power series, but how would you prove it? BTW there is another method.